# Can you determine the speed needed to make a corner with using centripetal as well as centrifugal force?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, centripetal-force, centrifugal-force

A car weighing 800kg is driving on a motorway. It accelerates from 0 to 100 km / h in 3.5 s; this acceleration is only limited by the grip of the tires.

a)How fast can it go in a curve with a radius of 500m?

b)How fast could it go if the curve were inclined 10∘ from the center of the curve?

My solution;
a) Since the car acceleration is limited by the grip,the friction force will surely play a role.So we need to figure out what is the friction force. I did that like this

$$ F_a = F_r $$

$$ F_a = m * a $$
$$ a = \frac{v}{t} --> a = 7,4 m/s^2 $$

If we plug this back into the formula for Fa and if we write the formula for Fr we get this

$$ m * a = \mu * m * g $$
$$ \mu = \frac{a}{g} --> 0,809 $$

Since the speed should be limited by both the centrifugal and centripetal force(if the speed exceeds any of these we will fly out of the curve) So I did it like this

$$Fr = Fz$$
$$ \mu * m * g = m *\frac{v^2}{r} $$
$$ v = \sqrt{\mu * g * r} $$
$$ v = 226,8 km/h $$

Now can I calculate this using the centrifugal force? Because the principal should be the same,since in case when we exceed either of these forces the same result should happen.I've tried calculating it as well but I've been stuck at this part.

$$ \mu * m * g = m *\omega^2 r^2 r $$

I cannot seem to able to get an actual expression for v here.Im still conviced that I should be able to solve both part a and b of this question with both centrifugal and centripetal force,its just my math is lacking.If my intuition and understanding is leading me astray,please let me know.

Looking forward to your answers!

Comment: In an inertial reference frame (e.g., an observer standing on the "sidelines" watching the action), only centripetal force exists.  Centrifugal force is a pseudo force that exists inside an accelerating reference frame (e.g., inside an automobile rounding a corner).

Comment: Hmmm okay,that is quite interesting.So it actually comes down from the refrence frame.Since here it isnt stated explicitly,you would simply have to assume one or the other right?

Comment: You can assume any reference frame you want to, but when working physics problems, you don't want to switch reference frames in the middle of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For circular motion, $v=\omega r$.

$$\dfrac{mv^2}r=\dfrac{m(\omega r)^2}{r}=m\omega^2r$$

Comment: Ohh okay now I get it,I've been able to do it as well now.I totaly forgot we can write omega like that.Thank you!